# SQL split string and get NULL values instead of empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

How to split string and get NULL values instead of empty string.

I am particularly interested in two methods `STRING_SPLIT` and `XML`.
I wish this query:

```
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT('a,b,,d', ',');
```

would return in third row `NULL` instead of empty string.
Is there any easy way to achieve it i.e. with special characters? I mean something like:

```
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT('a,b,[null],d', ',') -- this, of course, wouldn't go
```

I wish I could extract NULLs from string using `XML` method:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       varchar(8000),
   @Delimiter  char(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN (SELECT [value] = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)')
      FROM (SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i));
```

Code grabbed from here: https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/t-sql-queries/string-split

Comment: I think, best way is to create function using CLR and .Net

Comment: @AlexSham at the link I provided it is proven that STRING_SPLIT is the best as long as performance is tested. Maybe CLR is best for some other reason you do not mention. I am looking for simple solution to methods I ask.

Comment: `NULLIF(value, '')`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wrap the returned value with `NULLIF`:

```
SELECT NULLIF([value],'') FROM STRING_SPLIT...
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see, the value in between commas with nothing in between is actually showing up as empty string.  So, you could use a `CASE` expression to replace empty string with `NULL`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT('a,b,,d', ',')
)

SELECT
    value,
    CASE WHEN value = '' THEN NULL ELSE value END AS value_out
FROM cte;
```

Comment: I was afraid of the answer based on `CASE`:-)

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin Same here.  The demo tool I use, DBFiddle, does not show `NULL` explicitly, it just shows empty rows.