# Replace empty string with NULL in XML variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I wish this query would return NULL instead of empty string.

```
declare @str varchar(max)='A,,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z'; -- please notice missing B
declare @xmlstr XML
set @xmlstr = CAST(('<rows><row><col>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,';','</col></row><row><col>'),',','</col><col>') + '</col></row></rows>') AS XML)

SELECT
     t.n.value('col[1]','nvarchar(max)') as Col1
    ,t.n.value('col[2]','nvarchar(max)') as Col2
    ,t.n.value('col[3]','nvarchar(max)') as Col3
FROM
    @xmlstr.nodes ('/rows/row') AS t(n)
```

This example comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39752683/1903793

From the answer: [SQL split string and get NULL values instead of empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422666/sql-split-string-and-get-null-values-instead-of-empty-string) I know it can be fixed by easy wrap with `NULLIF` function:

```
SELECT
     nullif(t.n.value('col[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'') as Col1
    ,nullif(t.n.value('col[2]','nvarchar(max)'),'') as Col2
    ,nullif(t.n.value('col[3]','nvarchar(max)'),'') as Col3
```

However I wonder if it might be alternatively fixed by manipulating with **XML variable** directly, not afterwards.

Note. My question follows [SQL split string and get NULL values instead of empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422666/sql-split-string-and-get-null-values-instead-of-empty-string) Please do not mark it as dupe because I have not received answer for XML method.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't already behave like this? `SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML('1,2,,3', ',')` will return a table with a `NULL` for the third row. You actually have to add `ISNULL` to get it to behave the opposite way. If you could include an example of an actual call and the desired output in this question itself, that might help.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I edited my question

Comment: Yeah, now it's *completely* different. The XML variable still does not need "fixing", though, you can just use `col[1]/text()[1]`, `col[2]/text()[1]` for the value selectors (i.e. same approach as the previous version: select the `text()`). In the version as it is now I'm pretty sure you *can't* do this by tweaking the XML alone, because `col[2]` is only going to be `NULL` if there is no second `col` node, and if there is no such node then logically there cannot be a `col[3]` either.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Can you please put it as an answer with code structured? I cannot grasp the solution from your comment.

Comment: I mean replacing `t.n.value('col[2]','nvarchar(max)') as Col2` with `t.n.value('col[2]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') as Col2` (and similarly for the other columns). It's just not that interesting as an answer; I'd say `NULLIF` is fine as well.

Comment: What is supposed `/text()[1]` do? What is this strange construction doing?

Comment: `col[2]` is the second `col` node. `col[2]/text()` is the text node within `col[2]` (i.e. its contents, or `NULL` if it has no contents). `col[2]/text()[1]` is a technicality necessary for `value()` -- what we got back is actually a sequence of nodes, but `value()` wants only one node, so we select the first (and also only) one. Consult online material on XPath for more.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin You might read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43242238/5089204) to find more about `text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The credit for this answer is entirely to Jeroen Mostert. For details please see his comments.

```
declare @str varchar(max)='A,,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z'; -- please notice missing B
declare @xmlstr XML
set @xmlstr = CAST(('<rows><row><col>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,';','</col></row><row><col>'),',','</col><col>') + '</col></row></rows>') AS XML)

SELECT
     t.n.value('col[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') as Col1
    ,t.n.value('col[2]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') as Col2
    ,t.n.value('col[3]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') as Col3
FROM
    @xmlstr.nodes ('/rows/row') AS t(n)
```